# How do I define a relationship between groups of table records?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

I am working on an application that takes a survey of questions from a user via a web interface. The questions are standalone, but questions may be shown or hidden based on answers to previous questions.

Consider the following Schema:

Question -> hasMany -> LogicGroup -> hasMany -> LogicCondition

A LogicGroup is a group of conditions (LogicCondition). Each condition may be something like:

```
Question 1 answered 'A'
Question 2 answered 'D'
```

Based on both of these being fulfilled, the question that the user is approaching WILL be shown to them. Otherwise, it would be hidden.

So essentially, the question will have 1 or more 'LogicGroup', each of which contains 1 or more 'LogicCondition'.

**The part I am primarily struggling with**

Each of these LogicGroup and LogicCondition can be AND / OR / or combinations of the two. I am not sure how to code/architect the logic that would allow the database to define whether two groups are related via an 'AND' or an 'OR'.

*What is the best way to do this?*

EDIT: Here is an image that shows loosely the relationship visually.

[image: detail visual]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the *Or* vs. *And*, how are you going to prioritize the order of operations when a Group has both operators? Simply top to bottom?

Here's what I would use as a database schema based the order of operations being "top to bottom":

**logicrules** (one row represents the image your question)

- id
- description

**logicrulesgroups** (one row represents either Group 1 or Group 2 in your image)

- id
- logicrules_id (FK to logicrules)
- description
- sort_value (Assigned 1 for the first Group, increment for every subsequent Group for the same logicrules_id)
- operator (values: AND, OR, null (use null when sort_value = 1))

**conditions** (one row represents a single question for a group)

- id
- logicrulesgroups_id (FK to logicrulesgroups)
- sort_value (the first question is assigned 1, for every subsequent question for the same logicrulesgroups_id, the sort_value is incremented)
- question_id
- operator (values: AND, OR, null (use null when sort_value = 1))

**questions**

- id
- description
- *whatever the rest of your fields are*

---

**Cakephp terminology:**

- LogicRule

  - hasMany LogicRulesGroup
- LogicRulesGroup

  - belongsTo LogicRule
  - hasMany Condition
- Condition

  - belongsTo LogicRulesGroup
  - belongsTo Question
- Question

  - hasMany Condition